How to access fields of a table that is a foreign key to another in django rest api
I am writing dhango rest api.
I have ModelA with fields fldA1, fldA2 and fldA3
I have ModelB with fields fldB1, fldB2 and foreign key to ModelA
Now I have to write an api to read fldB1, fldB2 and ModelA.fldA3
How to do
